# React-Downshift - How to prevent clear by Escape key?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, dropdown, downshift

I am using React open source component [Downshift](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift) to build my custom dropdown.

The problem I am facing is that Downshift clears selected item (and calls the `onChange` callback with `null`) when user presses `Escape` key.

This clears my dropdown even though my dropdown does even not have an empty option.

How can I suppress this behavior and make it just close the opened dropdown (if it is open) and not to change the value.

Answer (score 3):

I guess I just figured it myself: I added a state reduced overriding default behavior:

```
  const stateReducer = (_, changes) => {
    switch (changes.type) {
      // Preventing from clearing value once ESC is pressed
      case Downshift.stateChangeTypes.keyDownEscape:
        return { isOpen: false };
      default:
        return changes;
    }
  };

  <Downshift stateReducer={stateReducer}>{/* your callback */}</Downshift>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna love this solution:

```
    case useSelect.stateChangeTypes.MenuKeyDownSpaceButton:
      setMessage(message + " ");
      break;
```